# Variable assigned inside subscribe is empty outside subscribe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, subscribe

Variable assigned inside subscribe is empty outside subscribe? why? I know that susbcribe is asynchronous, but, I don't know how await to render this var... please somebody help me and explain to me. I'm trying to get the value of a subscribe, to then render it in the html, but the value is only retrieved inside the subscribe event and not outside. What can I do to have it in the rest of the component. Thank you.

**My service;**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Api } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
import { environment as env } from 'src/environments/endpoints';
import { ICode } from '../components/login/login.interfaces';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

private rol$: Subject<any>            

  constructor(
    private api: Api,
  ) {
    this.rol$ = new Subject()
  }

  async verifyCode(data: ICode) {
    const res = await this.api.post(env.auth.login, data)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.error) {
          this.isAuthenticated = res.isAuth 
          this.setRol(res.rolUser)           
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        return false
      })

    return this.isAuthenticated
  }

  getRolUser$(): Observable<any> {
    return this.rol$.asObservable()
  }

  setRol(rolUser: any) {
    this.rol$.next(rolUser)
  }


}
```

}
**My component;**

```
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel-widgets',
  templateUrl: './panel-widgets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-widgets.component.scss']
})
export class PanelWidgetsComponent implements OnInit {

  rolUser$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private _auth : AuthService,
  ) { 
    }

  ngOnInit(){

    this._auth.getRolUser$().subscribe(e => this.rolUser$ = e)       
    
    console.log('Valor del subscribe __ ', this.rolUser$)    
 }

}
```

**Html template**

```
<p class="text">
     <span><b>Usuario : </b><p style="right: 0px;">{{usuario}}</p></span>
     <span><b>Email : </b>{{email}}</span>
     <span><b>Rol : </b>{{ rolUser$ | async }}</span>
 </p>
```

Comment: It's just another flavour of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: 1) you`re not asking a new question 2) you question does not include any code 3) your question already has an answer in the question I linked

Comment: @kvetis this is not intended to be a new question but an alternative approach to it (my approach is in the answers below). Oh about not including the code, thanks I have edited my question and added it.

Comment: Add the answer to the original question then.

Answer (score 1):

What causes this issue is because API calls in Angular are performed asynchronously, i.e The whole other parts of your program get executed regardless of whether the API call has returned the results or not. API calls can take some time to finish, and for this reason, making them run on their own thread helps to prevent glitches or stalls in your application. As a results, when you console.log() your global variable, it will be null.

So somehow, we want to wait for the API call until it finishes then we can successfully update our global variable.

A simple solution is using an Angular built-in class called  BehaviorSubject. I won't explain further about it, I will just show how it gets the job done.

globally declare your variable this way:

```
productBehaviourSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
```

And now, the subscribe body, will look like this:

```
 this.httpClient.get('your URL').subscribe((response)=>{ 
  this.productBehaviourSubject.next(response as Product);
});
```

Assuming that you are fetching a product. If it's a list of products, simply replace `this.productBehaviourSubject.next(response as Product);` with `this.productBehaviourSubject.next(response as Product[]);`

You can now access this variable globally with updated changes.
However now, to use `this.productBehaviourSubject`, you need to subscribe to it and do whatever that you want to do inside the body of the subscribe method. Like this

```
this.productBehaviourSubject.asObservable().subscribe( (product)=> {
      console.log(product)
      // Do your stuff here
      // And it can only be inside this method.
     // outside this method, values will be null.
    
    })
```

Now you can pass around `this.productBehaviourSubject` to any component, it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Put a `console.log` inside your subscribe callback and you'll notice that it'll be logged after the log outside of the subscription. Those 2 paths don't run sync.

You could look up [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and how to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) as well as the Documentation of [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/api)

Also, if you want to use the async pipe, there's no need to set the value inside the subscription itself

In you TS do something like this:

```js
public rolUser$: Observable<any> = this._auth.getRolUser$()
```

and with that, you have the Observable ready to go into your async pipe, just like you're already doing

```html
<span><b>Rol : </b>{{ rolUser$ | async }}</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, this works:

**Service**

```
  import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

  isAuthenticated: Boolean = false
  private rol$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');  

  constructor(
    private api: Api,
  ) {
  }
```

I use **BehaviorSubject** instead **Subject**

**And in my component:**

```
public rolUser$: Observable<any> | undefined;

ngOnInit() {
    this.rolUser$ = this._auth.getRolUser()
}
```

**and template html;**

```
<span><b>Rol : </b>
    {{ rolUser$ | async }}
</span>
```